# How to make exposure value in Unity HDRP visually equivalent to it in blender cycles

Tags: rendering, unity

I have rendered a series of videos in blender cycles to show some materials. And now, to replicate these materials in Unity HDRP, I try to keep all the parameters in same between these two platform: textures, distance between object and camera, depth of field, etc.

I find that the exposure value(1.0 by default) in blender cycles seems to be a parameter that cannot be corresponded to a physical value, while it(8.5 by default) in Unity HDRP seems to be more closed to a real exposure value of a camera. In a nutshell, I suspect that this parameter is not the same unit on different platforms.

How can I make exposure value in Unity HDRP visually equivalent to it in blender cycles(value = 1)? Apparently, setting it to the "same" 1.0 in Unity HDRP shows a different result. Is there any
rigorous mapping relationship of exposure value between blender cycles and Unity HDRP?

Here are the default render results from two platform:(result from Unity is slightly brighter)

[image: exposure = 1 in blender cycles]
exposure = 1 in blender cycles

[image: exposure = 8.5 in Unity HDRP]
exposure = 8.5 in Unity HDRP